# How can I accomplish this task in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am attempting to accomplish a task where I am using AngularJS so I am not sure how to implement potentially needed Javascript or if there is a way with using AngularJS.

I have this input:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="myCount" ng-disabled="button" min="1" value="1" id="myValue">
```

This code takes the value input by the user and places it in a variable:

```
$scope.myCount = document.getElementById("myValue").value;
```

Now, what I want is based on the number input, I want an array/object created for the number from the variable. For example:

```
for(i=0;i<myCount.length;i++){
  $scope.trackObject=[
    {name:i + "Objects"}
  ]
}
```

Here is what I am trying to accomplish with this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="pizza_tabs" role="tablist" ng-repeat="x in countPizzas">
    <li class="active"><a href="#pizza" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{x.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Sorry, I don't think I very well explained what I am trying to accomplish!

I want there to be a tab that contains the text "# Object", for each object created which the number of objects created is based on the user input. Does that make sense? So, if the user inputs 3, then 3 objects will be created, which I will be able to assign a name and whatever other properties to. 3 tabs are thusly created for the user to toggle through that will contain these properties. I hope that helps!

Comment: Just a note: your ng-repeat is on your <ul> element. So your repeating the whole <ul> element instead of the <li> element.

Comment: Each code snippet here has issues.  If you define exactly where you are having problems, we could start helping you.

Answer (score 0):

"what I want is based on the number input, I want an array/object created for the number from the variable"

```
for(i=0;i<myCount.length;i++){
   $scope.trackObject=[{name:i + "Objects"}]
 }

 //Try this
 var name;
 for(i=0;i<myCount;i++){ //because myCount is a number 
      name = i+"Objects";
      $scope.trackObject.push({name:name}); //add to the array
  }
```

Now for your last snippet, I didn't understand what you want to accomplish there.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by your question.

You have already set the ngModel to myCount so whatever you have typed into the input box would have been set to the ngModel - 'myCount'

There is no need to use jquery to get the value as such
"$scope.myCount = document.getElementById("myValue").value;"

As for the second part, i believe the user "I_Wrote_That" has already replied you on how to create an array of objects based on the input.

Answer (score 0):

At first, angular supports two way data binding. So you need not get the value of the element manually using `document.getElementById` etc.

```
$scope.myCount = document.getElementById("myValue").value;
```

Instead the value will be available in myCount by default.

Now to generate the objects based on count:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="pizza_tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#pizza" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"  ng-repeat="x in generateCounts(myCount)">{{x.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now in your controller:

```
$scope.generateCounts = function(myCount) {
     $scope.trackObject = [];
     for(var i=0; i < myCount; i++) {
        $scope.trackObject.push({name : i+"objects"});
     }
     return $scope.trackObject;
}
```

But this will not work still, it will give you duplicate key error.

So in your HTML, use `track by $index`

```
 <li class="active"><a href="#pizza" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"  ng-repeat="x in generateCounts(myCount) track by $index">{{x.name}}</a></li>
```